# How to reset a static struct inside a function

Tags: c++, function, struct, static

So let's say I have a function

```
struct coinTypes {
    int tenP = 0;
    int twentyP = 0;
    int fiftyP = 0;
};

coinTypes numberOfCoins(int coins)
{

    static coinTypes types;

    // incrementing structs values
}
```

Let's say I have used this function for some time, and values in coinTypes struct are no longer 0. Then I decided to use this function for another purpose and I need the values to be 0 again. Is there any way to reset coinTypes struct?

Comment: Bad design if you need that. You probably don't want a static there.

Comment: Bang your head against a hard object. Then think - Why am I using `static` for a C++ program that has the luxury of OOP

Comment: Challenge accepted. P.S. It's a **very bad** program design though. I'll also provide a better solution in my answer.

Comment: Either pass the struct in as a reference parameter, making the user responsible for it, or create a Functor with it as a member, and provide some reset methods.

Comment: BTW. Why does this function return `coinTypes` if `coinTypes` is defined inside the function? How can you use it outside that function?

Comment: I agree this is a bad design, however of course you can reset the values to zero. Just set them like you would for a non-static struct (you will need to add some kind of flag, read by this function, to trigger when to perform the reset logic).

Comment: Wait. It's a type, not a variable. And this zeros are initializes. Where do you define a variable of `coinTypes` type?

Comment: I defined it above the function. It just has the same name, I'll change it to avoid confusion. It's also a struct

Comment: This is not valid code. Have you got it to compile?

Comment: PS: Other parts of the uk have 10p, 50p etc

Comment: Defined like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/l6W02rJ81FZlbeHQ)?

Comment: This is not 100% my code, but yeah it works

Comment: There is no variable declared.

Comment: Yes, correct, Andrei

Comment: Oh yeah Ed, you were right, it was wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are just misunderstanding what the keyword `static` does (you probably are), this is what you are asking for:

[run online](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kewRgIJe9wWmwpnC)

```
#include <iostream>

struct britishCoins {
    int tenP;
    int twentyP;
    int fiftyP;
};

britishCoins& getCoins () {
    static britishCoins coins {0, 0, 0};
    return coins;
}

void resetCoins () {
    getCoins() = {0, 0, 0};
}

britishCoins numberOfCoins(int coins)
{
    britishCoins& result = getCoins();
    result.tenP += coins / 10;
    //...
    return result;
}

int main () {
    std::cout << numberOfCoins(0).tenP << std::endl;
    std::cout << numberOfCoins(10).tenP << std::endl;
    std::cout << numberOfCoins(10).tenP << std::endl;
    std::cout << numberOfCoins(10).tenP << std::endl;
    std::cout << numberOfCoins(10).tenP << std::endl;
    resetCoins();
    std::cout << numberOfCoins(0).tenP << std::endl;
    std::cout << numberOfCoins(10).tenP << std::endl;
    std::cout << numberOfCoins(10).tenP << std::endl;
    std::cout << numberOfCoins(10).tenP << std::endl;
    std::cout << numberOfCoins(10).tenP << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
```

If you just want to convert `int coins` into `britishCoins` without storing it's value inside the function it's simple:

[run online](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qUl3pyO8JTIP5apD)

```
#include <iostream>

struct britishCoins {
    int tenP;
    int twentyP;
    int fiftyP;
};

britishCoins numberOfCoins(int coins)
{
    britishCoins result;
    result.fiftyP = coins / 50;
    coins %= 50;
    result.twentyP = coins / 20;
    coins %= 20;
    result.tenP = coins / 10;
    return result;
}

int main () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        britishCoins coins = numberOfCoins(130);
        std::cout << coins.fiftyP << "*50 + " << coins.twentyP << "*20 + " << coins.tenP << "*10" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
2*50 + 1*20 + 1*10
2*50 + 1*20 + 1*10
2*50 + 1*20 + 1*10
```

Comment: Thanks much, I see my mistakes now

Comment: You understood what I meant even though I made a mistake in my code.. You're great

Comment: All you have done is wrapped a global variable with function calls. You may as well just use a global variable outright.

Comment: @NeilKirk The  first part is answering the question verbatim. He asked for a way to "reset the **static** variable". See the second part for an alternative I propose based on my guess about what the author of the question really wanted to ask for.

Comment: Should be `britishCoins` not `englishCoins`

Answer (score 0):

Dont use static in this case. Try to use:
Class Coin with object params coinType, couinNumber for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am resetting a static var:

```
bool MyString::toke(const MyString& src, const MyString& tgt, MyString &token) {

    uint tgt_pos;
    static MyString tmp = "default";
    static bool found = false;

    if (tmp == "default")
        tmp = src;
    else if (!tmp.length())
        tmp = src;

    // reset static tmp for next pass
    tmp = "";
}
```